# In Scala, how can you check whether a specifc Component was clicked by pattern matching on the MouseEvent object?

Tags: swing, scala

This [book](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/gui-programming.html) seems to suggest every that an event is an instance of an event case class.

> "For instance, pressing a button will create an event which is an instance of the following case class: 
>   case class ButtonClicked(source: Button)"

1) Applyin this logic, does this mean that pressing the mouse will create an event which is an instance of the following case class?:

```
case class MousePressed(source: Component, point: java.awt.Point, modifiers: Modifiers, clicks: Int, triggersPopup: Boolean)(peer: java.awt.event.MouseEvent)
```

2) To do pattern matching on the object to detect whether a specific Component has been pressed by the mouse, is this code correct?:

```
listenTo(mouse.clicks)
  reactions += {
    case MousePressed(nameOfComponent,_,_,_,_) => //some code you want to execute in response to that component being pressed //
  }
```

3) and am I also right in thinking that the other arguments can be checked as well, say for example

```
    case MousePressed(nameOfComponent,point,modifier,3,true)
```

makes for a very specific pattern: a specific component at a specific point with a certain modifier, on its third click, and triggers pop up? (it's probably not very practical)

4) What does the Modifier argument do?

Comment: Err... not really following you this time. The constructors define *how* an object is created - as to "how much", it is always one per constructor *call*. It's just that for case classes, you get a "free" extractor that gives you a possible pattern match corresponding to the class's default constructor - but those are separate things in general.

Comment: I seem to be confusing myself.. sorry I somehow didn't read the header for the MousePressed case class in the API and have been going around in circles. The quote from the book (above) is rather confusing for me. I have modified the question now.. hopefully the last block of code is correct?

Comment: much better question now, although to be honest you could have gotten to the answer of e.g. 3) by yourself. I'm not trying to discourage you to ask questions - rather, I want to encourage you not be afraid to experiment :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **It will create an instance of `scala.swing.event.MousePressed`**. As I said in the comment, it doesn't matter what constructor is used during initialization, it will be the same class with the same field. The only difference is that you have a pattern available that corresponds to the primary constructor, since it's a case class.

2) **Yes**, and **no**. *Formally* you're correct - specifically in this case you say:

- "for **this** component",
- "capture any `MousePressed` event, and give me access to the `component` field through `nameOfComponent` (I don't care about the rest)."

*Practically* your code won't work as you expect, since event handlers in Swing are registered **per component**, and it seems Scala Swing follows that pattern. That means unless you say explicitly, you will only get events from the components `mouse` module you've used `listenTo` on - and no other component, **not even it's children**.

So, if you would e.g. want to listen on the component itself and its *direct* children (*not* children of children), you would add:

```
contents.foreach(child => listenTo(child.mouse.clicks))
```

This is of course standard Scala code - I'll leave it to you to adapt it to your needs.

And finally for this point - usually it's best to define a pattern match for specific events for specific components, instead of a "general" handler - the latter solution is useful only in a minority of cases, like making custom components.

3) **Correct,** here you say "I want to match `MousePressed`, give me access to the `component`, `point` and `modifier` fields through variables `nameOfComponent`,`point`, and `modifier`, *and* I want the matched event to have `clicks == 3` and `triggersPopup == true`". The last two are called **constant patterns**.

4) This is really a separate question, but I'll bite, this time. They're [the same thing as in Java's Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html) - it's a special field for storing flags related to the event. They're even the same type as in Java - [`Modifiers` is a type alias for `Int`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.swing.event.Key%24@Modifiers=Int). Basically, those are numbers which convey additional info about the event. For example, if you want to check whether this was a left click, you would use:

```
import java.awt.event.{InputEvent => AWTEvent} //so that we don't confuse it with the Scala class

...

case MousePressed(_,_,AWTEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK,_,_) => ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to print a line telling you where the mouse clicked.

```
listenTo(mouse.clicks)
  reactions += {
    case e:MousePressed => println("press "+e.point)
}
```